# No options in dynamically provided intent for widget

Tags: ios, android-intent, swiftui, widget

I'm trying to implement dynamically provided options for my iOS 15 widget. So far I successfully implemented static intent parameters, and now I wanted to extend it with dynamically provided ones.
The dynamic parameter in my *.intentdefinition* file is called `HotspotList` and has type `String`.

I have defined a struct where I have also saved a list of `availableHotspots`:

```
struct Hotspot: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {

...

static var availableHotspots = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "hotspots") as? [String] ?? [] 
}
```

I have checked that this array is successfully saved with `print(Hotspot.availableHotspots)` somewhere in my main View.

Now I want to use this array in my IntentHandler.swift file:

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, WidgetConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        
        return self
    }
    
    func provideHotspotListOptionsCollection(for intent: WidgetConfigurationIntent) async throws -> INObjectCollection<NSString> {
        let hotspots: [NSString] = Hotspot.availableHotspots.map { element in
            let nsstring = element as NSString
            
            return nsstring
        }
        
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: hotspots)

        return collection
    }
    
    func defaultHotspotList(for intent: WidgetConfigurationIntent) -> String? {
                
        return "thisIsJustATest"
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]
[image]

I see that the intent is implemented correctly, because defaultHotspotList() returns the default parameter. But somehow provideHotspotListOptionsCollection() doesn't return the list of Strings. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I also tried the non-async option of the function:

```
    func provideHotspotListOptionsCollection(for intent: WidgetConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let hotspots: [NSString] = Hotspot.availableHotspots.map { element in
            let nsstring = element as NSString

            return nsstring
        }

        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: hotspots)
        print(collection)
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
```

Comment: You say "main view"? as in the iOS app? The UserDefaults as you have defined them are not shared between the iOS app and the Widget Extension. Look unto UserDefaults with AppGroup

Comment: Ooooh yes I see. So that was an easy one. Thanks @loremipsum!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the hint of @loremipsum I was able to fix it by myself. For anyone interested, here's my solution:

I added the following lines in my MainView in the App target:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("hotspots", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.<<bundleID>>"))
    var hotspotData: Data = Data()
    
...

        save(hotspots: miners)

...

    func save(hotspots: [String]) {
        do {
            hotspotData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: hotspots, requiringSecureCoding: false)
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
            
        } catch let error {
            print("error hotspots key data not saved \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

and then to retrieve the data in the IntentHandler.swift:

```
import Intents
import SwiftUI

class IntentHandler: INExtension, WidgetConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    @AppStorage("hotspots", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.<<bundleID>>"))
    var hotspotData: Data = Data()

    func provideHotspotListOptionsCollection(for intent: WidgetConfigurationIntent) async throws -> INObjectCollection<NSString> {

        var hotspots: [String] {
            
            var hotspots: [String]?
            
            do {
                hotspots = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(hotspotData) as? [String]
            } catch let error {
                print("color error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                
            }
            return hotspots ?? []
        }
        
        let NSHotspots: [NSString] = hotspots.map { element in
            let nsstring = element as NSString
            
            return nsstring
        }
        
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: NSHotspots)
        
        return collection
    }
```